# How to show the edge of next card only using PageView

Tags: flutter, dart

so I guess the title is clear,
i used a *PageView.builder with its viewportFraction* made my app show both the top and bottom edges of the next cards
and i want to display **only** the bottom edge

[image]

Comment: that depends, do you also want to see the bottom edge?

Comment: show some code else increase your viewport

Comment: We can achieve with Listview. Are you okay with Listview?

Comment: i only want to see the bottom edge not the top one , 
about showing code , its just a PageView with these cards and i added the viewportFraction = 0.8 but as it shows both top and bottom edges 
about ListView solution : yes provide the solution but i would really appreciate it if its solved using PageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: PageView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        controller: PageController(
            viewportFraction: .8, initialPage: 0, keepPage: false),
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
            child: Image.network(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
            child: Image.network(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
            child: Image.network(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?"),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 100),
            child: Image.network(
                "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Increase the padding, make it 100 to 120

Comment: you can use it inside stack widget with positioned top 0 or -20